# How to keep just one specific marker from a markercluster?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a markercluster.

I have a listener for every marker in it.

When I click on it, I go into its listener routine.

Now how do I keep this marker and remove all others from the cluster?

I did this but it somehow doesnt work

```
temp.push(this);
markerCluster_new.addMarkers(temp);
markerCluster_old.clearMarkers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove all the markers
- Reinsert the one you want to keep